# Variables not working as expected inside Select-Object expression statement

Tags: powershell, variables, select-object

I'm attempting to add a custom column to the table output of some objects retrieved from our MECM instance.

The following code shows the precise format of the code, only gathering data from `Get-Process` instead.

```powershell
$types = @{
     "chrome" = "This is Chrome"
     "winlogon" = "This is winlogon"
}

$procs = Get-Process | Select Name,Id | Where { ($_.Name -eq "winlogon") -or ($_.Name -eq "chrome") }
$procsCustom = $procs | Select Name,Id,@{
    Name = "TestColumn"
    Expression = {
        $name = $_.Name
        $types.$name
    }
}
$procsCustom  | Format-Table
```

This code functions as expected:

```
Name        Id TestColumn
----        -- ----------
chrome   12428 This is Chrome
chrome   12448 This is Chrome
chrome   12460 This is Chrome
winlogon   880 This is winlogon
winlogon  5076 This is winlogon
```

When I do the same thing for my actual code:

```powershell
$refreshTypes = @{
    1 = "Manual Update Only"
    2 = "Scheduled Updates Only"
    4 = "Incremental Updates Only"
    6 = "Incremental and Scheduled Updates"
}

$colls = Get-CMCollection | Where { ($_.RefreshType -eq 4) -or ($_.RefreshType -eq 6) }
$collsCustom = $colls | Select Name,RefreshType,@{
    Name = "RefreshTypeFriendly"
    Expression = {
        $type = $_.RefreshType
        $refreshTypes.$type
    }
}
$collsCustom | Format-Table
```

The custom column is not populated:

```
Name         RefreshType RefreshTypeFriendly
----         ----------- -------------------
Collection 1           6
Collection 2           4
```

The following code shows that `$_.RefreshType` is being parsed correctly:

```powershell
$collsCustom = $colls | Select Name,RefreshType,@{
    Name = "RefreshTypeFriendly"
    Expression = {
        $_.RefreshType
    }
}
$collsCustom  | Format-Table
```

```
Name         RefreshType RefreshTypeFriendly
----         ---------- -------------------
Collection 1          6                   6
Collection 2          4                   4
```

The following code forces a fake value for `$type` in the expression scriptblock and shows that the rest of the code works:

```powershell
$collsCustom = $colls | Select Name,RefreshType,@{
    Name = "RefreshTypeFriendly"
    Expression = {
        $type = 1
        $refreshTypes.$type
    }
}
$collsCustom | Format-Table
```

```
Name         RefreshType RefreshTypeFriendly
----         ----------- -------------------
Collection 1           6 Manual Update Only
Colleciton 2           4 Manual Update Only
```

So why in the world does the intended code output nothing in the custom column? Given the examples I've provided above, I'm stumped.

FWIW I've also tried using the array syntax (`$refreshTypes[$type]`) instead of the object property syntax (`$refreshTypes.$type`) but I get the same behavior.

Thanks for your time.

Environment:
Win10 x64 20H2
Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your type isn't being interpreted as an int.  Try casting $type to Int

Try this

```
Expression = {
    [int]$type = $_.RefreshType
    $refreshTypes.$type
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! That's strange, because I had also tried defining `$refreshTypes` using strings as keys (i.e. `"1" = "Manual Update Only"`), and it still didn't work. `$_.RefreshType.GetType()` returns `System.UInt32`, so maybe that's the issue? As a career IT pro, with nearly a decade since any CS classes, let's just say I'm not so good with types anymore.

Comment: @mmseng, yes, that's the issue: Lookup keys must be of the exact same type as the actual keys in the hashtable. With string keys, you could have done `$refreshTypes."$type"`